# How to avoid singleton behavior with a node-gyp generated node module?

Tags: c++, node.js, singleton, require, node-gyp

I have a nodejs app using a computation-intensive C++ add-on that I built with node-gyp.

Within my add-on I have a singleton class which is essentially some static data container, initialized by users before calling any other function of the module.

Therefore, when the app is used by more than one user, each instance will actually access the same C++ singleton, which is of course terrible.

I understand that this is caused by the require instruction

```
var myCppModule = require('./myCppModule');
```

effectively behaving like a singleton.

I know how to get around the issue for nodejs modules by exporting a constructor of the module and call new:

```
var myNodejsModule = new (require('./myNodejsModule'))();
```

But is there a way to achieve the same thing with my node-gyp generated module? This would make sure that each user has his own instance of the lib, and therefore his own singleton.